# Is there Any way to run for loop in HTML File (Extension)?

Tags: php, html, loops

You have got the question right Suppose that I have a div and I have to use it for 30 times in a row there is going to be variables in the which they will change their value. So my question is there anyway to create a for loop in html or php.
**Any Help Is much appriciated**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div>
                <img src="images/$images[$i]">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>$Title[$i]</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
            <p>Ratings: 6.3/10</p>
            <p> Reviews: <?php echo $review[$i] ;?></p>
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can do with php

```
<div class="row">
     <?php for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){?>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div>
                <img src=<?php echo "'images/".$images[$i]."'" ?>>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3><?php echo $Title[$i] ?></h3>
            </div>
            <div>
            <p>Ratings: 6.3/10</p>
            <p> Reviews: <?php echo $review[$i] ;?></p>
            </div>

        </div>
     <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way this can be done:

```
$content = "";
$num_divs = 30;
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_divs; $i++) {
    $content .= "<div>...</div>";
}
```

Then, in your html,

```
<?php echo $content ?>
```